# Splitting up a correlation matrix in R

Tags: r, correlation, data-manipulation, r-corrplot

I have a dataset with 400 variables that I am using to produce a correlation matrix (i.e. comparing each variable against one another). The resulting matrix has the following structure:

|  | var_1 | var_2 | var_3 | var_4 | var_5 | var_6 | etc (to 400 vars) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| var_1 | 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.8 |  |
| var_2 | 0.1 | 1 | 0.15 | 0.3 | 0.11 | 0.6 |  |
| var_3 | 0.2 | 0.15 | 1 | 0.47 | 0.05 | 0.72 |  |
| var_4 | 0.2 | 0.3 | 0.47 | 1 | 0.25 | 0.54 |  |
| var_5 | 0.4 | 0.11 | 0.05 | 0.25 | 1 | 0.84 |  |
| var_6 | 0.8 | 0.6 | 0.72 | 0.54 | 0.84 | 1 |  |
| etc (to 400 vars) |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I am then generating a figure of the correlation matrix with the corrplot package using the following command:

```r
library(corrplot)
corrplot(df, order = "hclust", 
         tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45)
```

Unsurprisingly, this results in a very large figure that is interpretable. I was hoping to split up my matrix and then create separate correlation matrix figures (realistically 20 pairwise comparisons of variables at a time). I am struggling to find code that will help me split up my matrix and plug it back into corrplot. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll need to write to the `corrplot` maintainer to ask for an enhancement, or edit the `corrplot` function yourself to make this happen, but it isn't currently written in a way that makes such a modification easy.  If you wanted subsets of the original set of variables before reordering it would be pretty easy.

Comment: `findCorrelation` in caret package can find highly correlated variables that can then be removed.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to split your correlation matrix up and then plot all submatrices. The challenge with that is that you are setting `order=`, which you (apparently) do not know a priori. Assuming you want to allow `corrplot` to determine the order, then here's a method: plot the whole thing first capturing the function's return value (which contains order information), then split the matrix and plot the components.

Helpful: while most plotting functions operate by *side-effect* (creating a plot, not necessarily returning values), some return information useful for working with or around its plot components. `corrplot` is no different; from `?corrplot`:

```
Value:

     (Invisibly) returns a 'list(corr, corrTrans, arg)'. 'corr' is a
     reordered correlation matrix for plotting. 'corrPos' is a data
     frame with 'xName, yName, x, y, corr' and 'p.value'(if p.mat is
     not NULL) column, which x and y are the position on the
     correlation matrix plot. 'arg' is a list of some corrplot() input
     parameters' value. Now 'type' is in.
```

With this, let's get started. I'll be using `mtcars`

1. Plot the whole thing. If this takes a long time or you don't want it to try to plot in R's graphics pane, then uncomment the `png` and `dev.off`, intended just to dump the plot itself to "nothing". (`"NUL"` is a windows thing ... I suspect `"/dev/null"` should work on most other OSes, untested.)

   ```r
   # png("NUL")
   CP <- corrplot::corrplot(M, order="hclust", tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
   # dev.off()

   str(CP)
   # List of 3
   #  $ corr   : num [1:6, 1:6] 1 0.4 0.8 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.4 1 0.84 0.11 ...
   #   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
   #   .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "var_1" "var_5" "var_6" "var_2" ...
   #   .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "var_1" "var_5" "var_6" "var_2" ...
   #  $ corrPos:'data.frame':  36 obs. of  5 variables:
   #   ..$ xName: chr [1:36] "var_1" "var_1" "var_1" "var_1" ...
   #   ..$ yName: chr [1:36] "var_1" "var_5" "var_6" "var_2" ...
   #   ..$ x    : num [1:36] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
   #   ..$ y    : num [1:36] 6 5 4 3 2 1 6 5 4 3 ...
   #   ..$ corr : num [1:36] 1 0.4 0.8 0.1 0.2 0.2 0.4 1 0.84 0.11 ...
   #  $ arg    :List of 1
   #   ..$ type: chr "full"
   ```
2. `rownames(CP$corr)` (which equals `colnames(CP$corr)`) provides the column/row order, so we can use those as our ordering (resulting from `order="hclust"`.

   ```r
   M_reord <- M[rownames(CP$corr), colnames(CP$corr)]
   M_reord
   #       var_1 var_5 var_6 var_2 var_3 var_4
   # var_1   1.0  0.40  0.80  0.10  0.20  0.20
   # var_5   0.4  1.00  0.84  0.11  0.05  0.25
   # var_6   0.8  0.84  1.00  0.60  0.72  0.54
   # var_2   0.1  0.11  0.60  1.00  0.15  0.30
   # var_3   0.2  0.05  0.72  0.15  1.00  0.47
   # var_4   0.2  0.25  0.54  0.30  0.47  1.00
   ```
3. Now we split the matrix up. For this example, I'll assume your "20" is really "3". Some helper objects:

   ```r
   grps <- (seq_len(nrow(M)) - 1) %/% 3
   grps
   # [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1
   eg <- expand.grid(row = unique(grps), col = unique(grps))
   eg
   #   row col
   # 1   0   0
   # 2   1   0
   # 3   0   1
   # 4   1   1
   ```

   where the row of `eg` counts columns-first (top-bottom then left-right), like so:

   [image: picture of corrplot with submatrices labels from 1 to 4]
4. Given a specific submatrix number (row of `eg`), plot it. Let's try "2":

   ```r
   subplt <- 2
   rows <- which(grps == eg[subplt, "row"])
   cols <- which(grps == eg[subplt, "col"])
   corrplot::corrplot(M[rows, cols], tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
   ```

   [image: lower-left submatrix corrplot]
5. If you want to automate plotting these (e.g., in an rmarkdown document, in `shiny`), then you can loop over them with:

   ```r
   for (subplt in seq_len(nrow(eg))) {
     rows <- which(grps == eg[subplt, "row"])
     cols <- which(grps == eg[subplt, "col"])
     corrplot::corrplot(M[rows, cols], tl.col="black", tl.srt=45)
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much - this worked perfectly!